# Trying to Set a Shortcut to a Directory

Tags: macos, terminal, directory

Im trying to run several different scripts on my Mac for data stored in different paths. So I put all said scripts into a folder. In order for a script to work, I have to be cd'd to a specific folder required for said script. I use the scripts to get different types of output (ex: Image volumes, MRI info, etc..).

I was wondering if there was a way to store all my scripts in one directory and assign a shortcut to it. That way, I can cd to my folder, and only type something like `$ScriptsFolder/Script_1` to have it. Ive seen this done in the FSL software package, where typing `$FSLDIR/data/standard` would give you the items in that folder.

UPDATE:

Im using `Script=/Users/ray/Documents/Script` which works until I close down my terminal to start a new one. Any way to make the setup permanent?

Comment: OSX is a UNIX like system. Perhaps taking a look at [this StackExchange post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1469/bash-directory-shortcuts) may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*EDITED*

Found this helpful in the end.

http://www.techradar.com/how-to/computing/apple/terminal-101-creating-aliases-for-commands-1305638

I used it to create a shortcut to my scripts which are all placed in a folder for easy referencing.